# mkdir creating directory in multiple locations

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to use a .cmd file to set up a program before use and part of that involves creating a directory. The structure of the directories is as follows:

```
main-
    |
    |--build-
    |       |
    |       setup.cmd
    |
    |--src-
          |
          main.py
```

What I want is for a directory called "files" to be created in the src directory by the file setup.cmd.

I have tried using the code:

```
mkdir "..\src\files"
```

but it creates the directory in both the src and build directories.

How can I make it so that it only creates the directory in the src directory?

**Edit:**
I want to run the python file after creating the directory. The code I have is:

```
mkdir "..\src\files"
python "..\src\main.py"
```

However, when I run it, it creates the directory in the build directory as well as the src directory.
If I remove the second line it creates the directory correctly.

Comment: Use in the batch file `setup.cmd` the command line `md "%~dp0..\src\files" 2>nul` which creates the wanted directory `main\src\files` independent on which directory is the current working directory of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file `setup.cmd` which can be any directory as defined by the process starting `cmd.exe`. `%~dp0` references drive and path of argument 0 of the batch file. That is the fully qualified directory name of the batch file directory always ending with a backslash. The command `md` can be also `mkdir`. Run `help` in a command prompt window and next `md /?` or `mkdir /?`.

Comment: There can be used as next line `python.exe "%~dp0..\src\main.py"` or `for %%I in ("%~dp0..\src\main.py") do python.exe "%%~fI"` for passing the absolute file name of the *Python* script file to *Python*. The script file `main.py` must be coded to work with current working directory of `python.exe` being different to the directory containing the interpreted *Python* script file. Many *Python* scripts do not work correct on current working directory is not the directory containing the script file.

Comment: A solution would be `for %%I in ("%~dp0..\src\main.py") do pushd "%%~dpI" && (python.exe "%%~fI" & popd)` which makes the directory of `main.py` the current working directory for `cmd.exe` before starting `python.exe` by calling the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory` being a null pointer and restoring the initial current working directory after `python.exe` terminated itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a small mistake in your command. Try md or mkdir instead of mk. The correct command for creating a directory using mkdir or md in a Windows batch file (.cmd) would be:

```
mkdir "..\src\files"
```

Comment: I tried both of those but they both had the same issue.

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `mkdir /?` or `md /?`.  What does that tell you about your answer?